# Create Groups in BuddyPress not showing

Tags: buddypress, usergroups

I have installed the BuddyPress plugin and as a user can't seem to be able to create a Group.  If I go to mydomain.com/members/my-username/groups/   I don't see a link to Create Groups.  But if I hand-type the Create at the end of this link: mydomain.com/members/my-username/groups/create  it displays it.
I think something is missing in the core perhaps.  I looked for some answers here but I could not find anything that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `.../wp-admin/admin.php?page=bp-settings`. Is this option selected?

```
Enable group creation for all users
```

If it is, then try switching to a WP theme like 2013. 
If the button appears, then the issue is in your theme.

edit:
BuddyPress doesn't provide a Create link on member profile pages. `mydomain.com/members/my-username/groups/`

The link will be here:
mydomain.com/groups/

You can add a link, but how you add it depends on exactly where you want it to appear.

Comment: I have that enabled already.  I can't switch my WP theme as I'm locked into it due to other customization.  Is there a way to correct this pragmatically?

Comment: Just switch it for a moment to confirm that the issue is in your theme.  Then check the group templates in your theme.

Comment: Thanks.  But no, it's not the theme!

Comment: Sorry....I missed what you said above.  You are right!  I don't know where I got that link from...but I you mentioned, that works just as well.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know why it automatically links it that way.  I went to Menus to update/change it, but I can't see how?  any tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

Create group solution 2017, 2017 (creating selection for group creation inside individual profile)
Follow the following 
Navigate t0: /wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/Members/single/group.php.
Then add the line below after line 12 such that it becomes line 13